# Segmentation Fault when moving binary outside directory

Tags: c, linux, gcc, segmentation-fault, gdb

Hello guys this is my first post here.

My problem is stupid I think but I can't find any solution, hope you can help me!

So, me and a friend are coding a small system monitor (learn better/fun), the code has 2 sections: the daemon and the command line interface (for now), when I compile the CLI section all went great, the daemon is particular one, because when I compile and I execute it in the compile directory it works without error! Magically, when I move out of the compile directory it gives me a segmentation fault!

Compiler: GCC

Here is the repository: https://github.com/StefanoBelli/JASM

Makefile:

```
 #!/usr/bin/make -f

SHELL=/bin/sh

####    CONFIGURATION    ####

CC=gcc
DEBUG=-g
CFLAGS=-O2 -pipe -Wall -std=c11 $(DEBUG)
LIBS=
BINOUT=jasm

####    SOURCES & RULES    ####

OBJS:=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))

install:$(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $(BINOUT) $(OBJS) 

clean:
    rm -fv *.o

.PHONY: install,clean
```

GDB Output:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/stefanozzz123/Devel/C.Cpp/JASM/bin/jasm 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 
0x00007ffff7a7db04 in vfprintf () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

Thank all of you guys! :)

EDIT: As you requested here is code:

jasm.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "queue.h"
#include "miscellaneous.h"
#include "ipc.h"




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  start_daemon();
  start_server();



}
```

ipc.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "ipc.h"
#include "miscellaneous.h"
#include "getter.h"


static void excecute_command(int fd, char *command)
{
  /*
   *  if get* -> modulo get
   *  if start* -> modulo dei moduli
   */

   // ************************** getter ***************************************
   if(strncmp("get", command, 3)==0) {  //ricevuto comando getter
     int i;
     //char buf[BUFSIZ];

     strcpy(command, &command[3]);

     for(i=0; i<NGETTER; i++) {
       if(strcmp(getterName[i], command)==0) { //se esiste getter
         log_string("getter found :)");
         getterFunction[i](fd);
         return;
       }
     }

     log_error("getter NOT found :(");
     write(fd, "null\0", 4);
     return;
   }

   // ************************** starter **************************************
   if(strncmp("start", command, 5)==0) {  //ricevuto start modulo



     log_error("starter NOT found :(");
     write(fd, "null\0", 4);
     return;
   }


   // ************************** miscellaneous ********************************
   if(strcmp("halt", command)==0) { //spegne jasm
        log_string("# halt and catch fire, done");
        write(fd, "halt\0", 4);
        exit(0);
   }



  /*if(strcmp("getVersion", command)==0) {
    write(fd, (void *)VERSION, sizeof(VERSION));
    log_string("server reply <version> with success");
    return;
  }*/
    log_error("request not found");
    write(fd, "null\0", 4);

}

void start_server()
{
int server_sockfd, client_sockfd;
int server_len;
socklen_t client_len;
struct sockaddr_in server_address;
struct sockaddr_in client_address;
int result;
fd_set readfds, testfds;

  server_sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  server_address.sin_family=AF_INET;
  server_address.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  server_address.sin_port=htons(SERVER_PORT);
  server_len=sizeof(server_address);

  bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, server_len);

  listen(server_sockfd, 5);

  FD_ZERO(&readfds);
  FD_SET(server_sockfd, &readfds);

  log_string("server started");

  while(1) {
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    char received[BUFSIZ];
    int fd;
    int nread;

    testfds=readfds;

    result=select(FD_SETSIZE, &testfds, (fd_set *)0, (fd_set *)0, (struct timeval *)0);

    if(result<1) {
      log_error("server fail");
      exit(1);
    }

    for(fd=0; fd<FD_SETSIZE; fd++) {
      if(FD_ISSET(fd, &testfds)) {
        if(fd==server_sockfd) {
          client_len=sizeof(client_address);
          client_sockfd=accept(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_len);
          FD_SET(client_sockfd, &readfds);
          sprintf(buf, "adding client on fd %d", client_sockfd);
          log_string(buf);
        } else {
          ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &nread);

          if(nread==0) {
            close(fd);
            FD_CLR(fd, &readfds);
            sprintf(buf, "removing client on fd %d", fd);
            log_string(buf);
          } else {
            read(fd, &received, BUFSIZ);
            sprintf(buf, "received from fd %d command <%s>", fd, received);
            log_string(buf);
            excecute_command(fd, received);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

miscellanous.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "miscellaneous.h"

char * getTime()
{
  time_t curtime;
  struct tm *loctime;
  static char *ret;

  curtime=time(NULL);
  loctime=localtime(&curtime);
  ret=asctime(loctime);
  ret[24]='\0';

  return ret;
}

void log_string(const char *message)
{
  FILE *fp;

  fp=fopen(LOGPATH, "a+");
  fprintf(fp, "[%s] %s\n", getTime(), message);
  fclose(fp);
}

void log_error(const char *message)
{
  FILE *fp;

  fp=fopen(LOGPATH, "a+");
  fprintf(fp, "[%s] ERROR: %s!\n", getTime(), message);
  fclose(fp);
}

void start_daemon()
{
  pid_t pid;
  char buf[BUFSIZ];

  log_string("boot");

  pid=fork();
  switch(pid) {
    case -1:
      log_error("fork fail");
      exit(1);
      break;

    case 0:
      log_string("fork success");
      break;

    default:
      exit(0);
      break;
  }

  if(setsid()<0) {
    log_error("setsid fail");
    exit(1);
  } else {
    log_string("setsid success");
  }

  //chiude i file descriptor di stdin, stdout, stderr
  close(0);
  close(1);
  close(2);

  sprintf(buf, "jasm started with pid %d and ppid %d", getpid(), getppid());

  log_string(buf);
}
```

Essentially these are main srcs...

GDB Backtrace says nothing as the program run stops immediately

Comment: show the code, run through gdb to get more info.

Comment: What does gdb's "backtrace" command tell you?

Comment: Do not just provide links, but post a [mcve].

Comment: With a handful of exceptions, you don't check the return from *any* of your system calls or other functions that can fail. You say the behavior changes "magically", but your system is trying to tell you what is happening, and you are deliberately ignoring that information. If you'd paid attention to it and checked it, you wouldn't have even had a question, because you'd know exactly what was happening already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question was tagged [gdb](/questions/tagged/gdb), let's see how gdb can help. In my case, I've installed the debuginfo files for libc, so that I can examine the arguments to C library functions, but you don't really need that in this case because we can find the bug by looking at the user's source code.

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: ./jasm 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x0, format=0x4019b1 "[%s] %s\n", 
    ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffbd38) at vfprintf.c:1295
1295    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x0, format=0x4019b1 "[%s] %s\n", 
    ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffbd38) at vfprintf.c:1295
#1  0x00007ffff7a693f7 in __fprintf (stream=<optimized out>, 
    format=<optimized out>) at fprintf.c:32
#2  0x000000000040149d in log_string (message=0x4019cb "boot")
    at miscellaneous.c:46
#3  0x000000000040151f in start_daemon () at miscellaneous.c:64
#4  0x0000000000401400 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf78) at jasm.c:31
```

The declaration for [vfprintf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vfprintf.html) is:

```
int vfprintf(FILE *restrict stream, const char *restrict format, va_list ap);
```

Even though we don't have the source code for vfprintf installed, we can see that the first argument passed to it, `s`, is a NULL stream pointer, and that is likely the cause of the seg fault.

Let's look at something we have source code for: frame 2, `log_string`.

```
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x000000000040149d in log_string (message=0x4019cb "boot")
    at miscellaneous.c:46
46    fprintf(fp, "[%s] %s\n", getTime(), message);
(gdb) print fp
$2 = (FILE *) 0x0
```

There it is.

```
#define LOGPATH "../../../../data/log/jasm.log"

void log_string(const char *message)
{
  FILE *fp;

  fp=fopen(LOGPATH, "a+");
  fprintf(fp, "[%s] %s\n", getTime(), message);
  fclose(fp);
}

void log_error(const char *message)
{
  FILE *fp;

  fp=fopen(LOGPATH, "a+");
  fprintf(fp, "[%s] ERROR: %s!\n", getTime(), message);
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Check the return value from `fopen`. It may be NULL depending on what directory the program is run from. It may be better to use an absolute pathname, possibly settable in the Makefile for portability.

```
write(fd, "halt\0", 4);
```

All of these should have a count of 5, to include the trailing NUL. (And it isn't absolutely necessary to explicitly include `\0` in the string literal, because C string literals implicitly have a `\0` at the end.)

Comment: I think you're right about the fopen() function as the path cannot be found if I move/copy binary to other path.

Comment: When I get home... I will try but I think that you're absolutely righ fopen() may return NULL... Thank you for now!!